# How do I solve this second-order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find $\theta(t)$ and I have the following differential equation: $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=5.36 \sin\theta - 0.028 \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2$$
$\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2$ is the square of the first derivative of $\theta(t)$.

Comment: Is this equal to $y'' = 5.36\sin(y) -0.026 (y')^4$, where $y=\theta$ ?

Comment: Not the 4th power, I corrected.

Comment: Do you want to solve it numerically or anatically (probably not possible) ?

Comment: This equation is possibly wrong/incomplete if it is to model a pendulum with friction. The friction force should always be opposite the movement direction, so $y''=5.36\sin(y)−0.026|y'|\,y'$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the equation numerically. Write it as the first order system (already including the suggestion by @LutzLehmann)
$$
\begin{cases}
w' = y\\
y' = 5.36 \sin w -0.028 y |y|
\end{cases}
$$

and use some standard numerical method like RK4. This is what you will get for $t\in[0, 8\pi]$, using the initial conditions $\theta(0)=0, \theta'(0)=3$:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Switch variables and then, write
$$-\frac{t''(\theta )}{t'(\theta )^3}=5.36 \sin (\theta)-\frac{0.028}{t'(\theta )^2}$$ Now, reduction of order $p(\theta )=t'(\theta )$ is simple.

Do not expect to have $\theta(t)$. Keep, if it exists, the implicit solution.